# Docker build doris FAILED: src/http/CMakeFiles/Webserver.dir/ev_http_server.cpp.o

Tags: c++, docker

I use

```
docker run -it -v /xxx/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /xxx/apache-doris-0.14.0-incubating-src/:/root/apache-doris-0.14.0-incubating-src/ apache/incubator-doris:build-env-1.3.1
```

to build Doris.
The error is as follows,

```
FAILED: src/http/CMakeFiles/Webserver.dir/ev_http_server.cpp.o
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/../bin/g++ -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I/var/local/thirdparty/installed/include -I../src -I../test -I../../gensrc/build -I/var/local/thirdparty/installed/gperftools/include -I/var/local/thirdparty/installed/include/thrift -I/var/local/thirdparty/installed/include/event -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++11 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -Wno-deprecated -Wno-vla -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_POSIX_TIME_STD_CONFIG -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -msse4.2  -Wno-attributes -DS2_USE_GFLAGS -DS2_USE_GLOG -faligned-new  -g -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -O3 -gdwarf-2 -DNDEBUG -fdiagnostics-color=always -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT src/http/CMakeFiles/Webserver.dir/ev_http_server.cpp.o -MF src/http/CMakeFiles/Webserver.dir/ev_http_server.cpp.o.d -o src/http/CMakeFiles/Webserver.dir/ev_http_server.cpp.o -c ../src/http/ev_http_server.cpp
../src/http/ev_http_server.cpp: In member function 'doris::Status doris::EvHttpServer::_bind()':
../src/http/ev_http_server.cpp:150:47: error: too many arguments to function 'int butil::tcp_listen(butil::EndPoint)'
  150 |     _server_fd = butil::tcp_listen(point, true);
      |                                               ^
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Doris 0.14.0 version is coresponding to `apache/incubator-doris:build-env-1.2` .
You can check this on Doris website [compilation section](https://doris.apache.org/installing/compilation.html#developing-mirror-compilation-using-docker-recommended)

Answer (score 0):

1. The error "too many arguments to function" can be fixed by eliminating the excess arguments (parameters) in the function .
2. Make sure that there is no syntax errors.
3. Need Docker V20.0 and docker-compose V2.10 or above.
4. The latest version of Apache Doris is V1.2.2. Check the newest version and hopefully you can solve the problem.
   https://doris.apache.org/docs/dev/releasenotes/release-1.2.2